# Entity Framework TPC with multiple inheritance

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF with TPC and I have a multiple inheritance lets say I have

Employee (abstract)

Developer (inherits from Employee)

SeniorDeveloper (inherits from Developer)

I inserted some rows in the database and EF reads them correctly.

BUT
When I insert a new SeniorDeveloper, the values get written to the SeniorDeveloper AND Developer database table, hence querying just the Developers (context.Employees.OfType()) also gets the recently added SeniorDevelopers.

Is there a way to tell EF, that it should store only in one table, or why does EF fall back to TPT strategy?

Comment: Those two problems are unrelated. Are you sure that data are really in `Developers` table = are you sure you have correctly configured TPC? The problem with `OfType` is not related to TPC / TPT. It is simply how `OfType` works.

Comment: OfType did work the same way in tpt...       
anyway, I inserted the values per hand to the database (Developers to Developers and SeniorDevelopers ONLY to SeniorDevelopers) and the OfType<Developers>() did give me only Developers and no SeniorDevelopers and that sounds a bit strange to me. 


I setted all up like said here http://cockneycoder.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/entity-framework-and-concrete-table-per-type-inheritance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like EF supports the multiple inheritance with TPC, we ended up using TPC for Employee to Developer and TPT between Developer and SeniorDeveloper...

Comment: It's not correct that EF doesn't support multiple inheritance with TPC. For EF >= 4.1 it works (`OfType` on a type simply translates into a UNION in SQL over the tables for this type and all derived types). INSERTS only insert into the table of the type being inserted, not into any tables of a base type. Since EF 4.1 uses the `ObjectContext` of EF 4.0 I also have doubt that it isn't supported in EF 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a reason for this, although I may not see the full picture and might just be speculating.

**The situation**

Indeed, the only way (that I see) for EF to be able to list only the non-senior developers (your querying use-case) in a TPT scenario by reading only the `Developer` table would be by using a discriminator, and we know that EF doesn't use one in TPT/TPC strategies.

Why?  Well, remember that all senior developers *are* developers, so it's only natural (and necessary) that they have a `Developer` record as well as a `SeniorDeveloper` record.

*The only exception is if `Developer` is an abstract type, in which case you can use a TPC strategy to remove the `Developer` table altogether.  In your case however, `Developer` is concrete.*

**The current solution**

Remembering this, and without a discriminator in the `Developer` table, the only way to determine if any developer is a non-senior developer is by checking if it is **not** a senior developer;  in other words, by verifying that there is no record of the developer in the `SeniorDeveloper` table, or any other subtype table.

*That did sound a little obvious, but now we understand why the SeniorDeveloper table must be used and accessed when its base type (Developer) is concrete (non-abstract).*

**The current implementation**

I'm writing this from memory so I hope it isn't too off, but this is also what Slauma mentioned in another comment.  You probably want to fire up a SQL profiler and verify this.

The way it is implemented is by requesting a UNION of *projections* of the tables.  These projections simply add a discriminator declaring their own type in some encoded way[1].  In the union set, the rows can then be filtered based on this discriminator.

*[1] If I remember correctly, it goes something like this:  0X for the base type, 0X0X for the first subtype in the union, 0X1X for the second subtype, and so on.*

**Trade-off #1**

We can already identify a trade-off:  EF can either store a discriminator in the table, or it can "generate one" at "run time".

- The disadvantages of a stored discriminator are that it is less space efficient, and possibly "ugly" (if that's an argument).  The advantages are lookup performance **in a very specific case** (we only want the records of the **base** type).
- The disadvantages of a "run time" discriminator are that lookup performance is not as good for that same use-case.  The advantages are that it is more space efficient.

At first sight, it would seem that sometimes we might prefer to trade a little bit of space for query performance, and EF wouldn't let us.

In reality, it's not always clear when;  by requesting a UNION of two tables, we just lookup two indexes instead of one, and the performance difference is negligible.  With a single level of inheritance, it can't be worse than 2x (since all subtype sets are disjoint).  But wait, there's more.

**Trade-off #2**

Remember that I said the performance advantage of the stored-discriminator approach would only appear in the specific use-case where we lookup records of the base type.  Why is that?

Well, if you're searching for developers that may or may not be senior developers[2], you're forced to lookup the `SeniorDeveloper` table *anyway*.  While this, again, seems obvious, what may be less obvious is that EF can't know in advance if the types will only be of one type or another.  This means that it would have to issue **two** queries in the worst case:  one on the `Developer` table, and if there is even one senior developer in the result set, a second one on the `SeniorDeveloper` table.

Unfortunately, the extra roundtrip *probably* has a *bigger* performance impact than a UNION of the two tables.  (I say probably, I haven't verified it.)  Worse, it increases for each subtype for which there is a row in the result set.  Imagine a type with 3, or 5, or even 10 subtypes.

And that's your trade-off #2.

*[2] Remember that this kind of operation could come from any part of your application(s), while the resolving the trade-off must be done globally to satisfy all processes/applications/users.  Also couple that with the fact that the EF team must make these trade-offs for all EF users (although it is true that they could add some configuration for these kinds trade-offs).*

**A possible alternative**

By batching SQL queries, it would be possible to avoid the multiple roundtrips.  EF would have to send some procedural logic to the server for the conditional lookups (T-SQL).  But since we already established in trade-off #1 that the performance advantage is most likely negligible in many cases, I'm not sure this would ever be worth the effort.  Maybe someone could open an issue ticket for this to determine if it makes sense.

**Conclusion**

In the future, maybe someone can optimize a few typical operations in this specific scenario with some creative solutions, then provide some configuration switches when the optimization involves such trade-offs.

Right now however, I think EF has chosen a fair solution.  In a strange way, it's almost cleaner.

**A few notes**

- I believe the use of union is an optimization applied in certain cases.  In other cases, it would be an outer join, but the use of a discriminator (and everything else) remains the same.
- You mentioned multiple inheritance, which sort of confused me initially.  In common object-oriented parlance, multiple inheritance is a construct in which a type has multiple base types.  Many object-oriented type systems don't support this, including the CTS (used by all .NET languages).  You mean something else here.
- You also mentioned that EF would "fallback" to a TPT strategy.  In the case of Developer/SeniorDeveloper, a TPC strategy would have the same results as a TPT strategy, since Developer is concrete.  If you really want a single table, you must then use a TPH strategy.

Comment: +1 for your great work! anyway I haven't been on the project (and on SO) for a while so I read it now. Well explained! (didn't verify)